# How can I populate multiple combo boxes at once?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, performance, oop

I'm creating a form in VB.NET where a user can edit a 7 day meal plan in 1 window. As shown in the image, the user selects the meal from combo boxes populated with the relevant food.

The code I'm writing should:

1. Populate each combo box with the currently selected meal from the plan database
2. Add items to each combo box with the relevant meals (e.g. Only meals of type Breakfast for Breakfast)
3. Save the users changes back to the database

As each meal is different and each day is different, I'm having to code every single combo box individually which will soon become unmanageable.

Here's the current code just to get Monday's meals loaded and the combo box items added:

```
    Private Sub getMealPlan()

        Dim day As Integer

        Dim mealPlan As MealPlan
        mealPlan = New MealPlan
        mealPlan.setMealPlanTableData()
        mealPlan.setMealTableData()

        Dim items As New List(Of String)()

        Dim meals As MealPlan
        meals = New MealPlan

        meals.setMealsTable("Pre-workout/Snack")

        With Me.monPreWorkout
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With

        With Me.monSnack
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With


        meals.setMealsTable("Breakfast")

        With Me.monBreakfast
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With


        meals.setMealsTable("Lunch/Dinner")

        With Me.monLunch
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With

        With Me.monDinner
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With


        meals.setMealsTable("Drink")

        With Me.monMornDrink
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With

        With Me.monAfternoonDrink
            .DataSource = meals.getTable
            .ValueMember = meals.getTable.Columns(0).ToString
            .DisplayMember = meals.getTable.Columns(1).ToString
        End With

        day = 0

        Me.monPreWorkout.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 0)
        Me.monBreakfast.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 1)
        Me.monLunch.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 2)
        Me.monDinner.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 3)
        Me.monSnack.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 4)
        Me.monMornDrink.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 5)
        Me.monAfternoonDrink.Text = mealPlan.getMealName(day, 6)

    End Sub
```

I'm going to have to copy this 7 days for each day of the week in addition to the insert code to reflect the users changes in the database. This can't be the best way.

How could I assign multiple combo box parameters at once or make this object orientated so that I don't have this mess?

[image: A form containing combo boxes for each meal for 7 days.]

```
Public Class MealPlan
    Inherits DatabaseTable

    Public Shared meals As DatabaseTable

    Public Sub setMealPlanTableData()

        table = MainConnectionAccess.conndb.runAdapter("SELECT `preWorkout`, `breakfast`, `lunch`, `dinner`, `snack`, `drink1`, `drink2` FROM `tblMealPlan`")
        setIndexToZero()

    End Sub

    Public Sub setMealTableData()

        meals = New DatabaseTable
        meals.setTableContents("SELECT `mealID`, `name` FROM `tblMeal`")

    End Sub

    Function getMealName(day, meal)

        Dim mealID As String
        Dim mealRow As Integer

        mealID = getValue(day, meal)
        setIndexToZero()

        For Each row As DataRow In meals.table.Rows

            If mealID = "0" Then

                Return ""

            ElseIf meals.getValue(currentRowIndex, 0) = mealID Then

                mealRow = currentRowIndex

            End If

            addRowCount()
        Next

        Return meals.getValue(mealRow, 1)

    End Function

    Public Sub setMealsTable(category As String)

        setTableContents("SELECT `mealID`, `name`, `category` FROM `tblMeal` WHERE category = '" + category + "'")

    End Sub

    Function getTable()

        Return table

    End Function

End Class
```

```
Public Class DatabaseTable

    Public table As DataTable
    Public currentRowIndex As Integer = 0
    Public currentColumnIndex As Integer = 0

    Public rowCountTotal As String
    Public columnCountTotal As String

    Public Sub setTableContents(mysqlstatement)

        table = MainConnectionAccess.conndb.runAdapter(mysqlstatement)
        setIndexToZero()

    End Sub

    Public Sub setIndexToZero()

        currentColumnIndex = 0
        currentRowIndex = 0
        rowCountTotal = table.Rows.Count
        columnCountTotal = table.Columns.Count

    End Sub

    Public Sub addColCount()

        currentColumnIndex = currentColumnIndex + 1

    End Sub

    Public Sub addRowCount()

        currentRowIndex = currentRowIndex + 1

    End Sub

    Public Sub initialise()

        table = New DataTable

    End Sub

    Function getCurrentValue(row, column)

        Dim actualRow As Integer
        Dim actualCol As Integer

        If IsNumeric(row) Then
            'nothing
        Else
            actualRow = currentRowIndex
        End If

        If IsNumeric(column) Then
            'nothing
        Else
            actualCol = currentColumnIndex
        End If

        Return table.Rows(actualRow).Item(actualCol).ToString()

    End Function

    Function getCurrentRow(column)

        Return table.Rows(currentRowIndex).Item(column).ToString()

    End Function

    Function getCurrentColumn(row)


        Return table.Rows(row).Item(currentColumnIndex).ToString()


    End Function

    Public Sub increaseQuantity(searchCol, searchValue, addCol, addValue)

        Dim currentRowIndex As Integer = 0
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

            If table.Rows(currentRowIndex).Item(searchCol) = Int(searchValue) Then
                table.Rows(currentRowIndex).Item(addCol) = table.Rows(currentRowIndex).Item(addCol) + addValue
                Exit Sub
            End If
            currentRowIndex += 1
        Next

        addNewItem(searchValue, addValue)

    End Sub

    Function getValue(row, column)

        Return table.Rows(row).Item(column).ToString()

    End Function

    Public Sub printQuantities()

        setIndexToZero()
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

            Console.WriteLine(getValue(currentRowIndex, 0) + "," + getValue(currentRowIndex, 1))
            addRowCount()
        Next

    End Sub

    Public Sub addNewItem(name, quantity)

        table.Rows.Add(name, quantity)

    End Sub

    Function getRowCount()

        Return table.Rows.Count()

    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What about learning the model view pattern ?

Comment: Which UI technology are you using?  In WPF, the way to go would be to have a view/viewmodel for a single day.  A backing collection of seven data items (for one week) would then map to seven instances of view, and set up right, most of that would just work without a whole lot of up-front coding on your part.

Comment: Could you provide some related code about 'mealPlan' ? It will help others make a test.

Comment: I'm using the Windows Form Application UI in Visual Studio to create the program.

Comment: I've added the classes relating to MealPlan and DatabaseTable. MealPlan inherits DatabaseTable. I'm unsure whether you can apply MVC to the UI I'm using.

Comment: Make a UserControl containing a single day and add 7 such UserControls on your form. The UserControl gets its date set when instantiated and either does the load and save itself when triggered by the containing form or that does it and the UserControl is passed to it (e.g. load me, save me).

Comment: Thanks Christoph, I'm going to explore UserControl and come back with the results.